# ERROR: Out of local stack

Tags: prolog

Мой код:

```
parent(pamela, bob).
parent(tom, bob).
parent(tom, liz).
parent(bob, ann).
parent(bob, patricia).
parent(patricia, jim).

ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y); ancestor(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).

% Кому Памела является предком?
query1(X) :- ancestor(pamela, X), write(X), nl, fail.
```

Запрос:

```
query1(X).
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
ERROR: Out of local stack
bob
ann
patricia
jim
```

Запускал в онлайн трансляторе ([ссылка](https://rextester.com/l/prolog_online_compiler)).

Что я сделал неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в двух словах, то вы получили бесконечную рекурсию "X предок Y, если X предок Z, если Z предок Z1, если Z1 предок Z2 и т.д."

Лечится это переносом рекурсии в хвост предложения:

```
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), ancestor(Z, Y).
```